# Reactjs - using Bootstrap classes is nearly impossible to do

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, api, bootstrap-4

How would I use a Bootstrap class like `class='col-6'` to make a grid system when I have to render my whole react application in a   `<div id="root"></div>` ? it applies relatively to the `<div id='root'>` not the actual body element.

in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
      </noscript>  
  </body>
</html>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

in `App.js` (react)

```
class FormApp extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <div className="formdiv col-6">
        <form className="ui form" id='form' method='post' action='/post'>
        <div className="field">
          <h4 className="ui horizontal divider header">
            Budget Calculator
          </h4>
          <div>
            <input  className="input-group-text" type="text" id="id" name='_id' placeholder='NOTE NAME' autoFocus required autoComplete="off"/>
          </div>
          <div className="two fields">
            <div className="field">
              <input  type='text' name='firstItem' placeholder='item' required autoComplete="off"/>
              <input  type='text' name='secondItem' placeholder='item' required autoComplete="off"/>
              <input  type='text' name='thirdItem'  placeholder='item' required autoComplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <input  type='number' name='firstPrice'   onKeyUp={calc} className='price'  placeholder='price'  required autoComplete="off"/>
              <input  type='number' name='secondPrice'  onKeyUp={calc} className='price'  placeholder='price'  required autoComplete="off"/>
              <input  type='number' name='thirdPrice'   onKeyUp={calc} className='price'  placeholder='price'  required autoComplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input  type='number' name='tBudget' id='totalbudget' placeholder="total price" readOnly/>
        </div>
        <button id='save-btn' type='submit' onClick={saveNote} className="ui teal labeled icon positive button">
            <span>save</span>
            <i className="add icon"></i>
        </button>
        </form>
        <button id='reset-form' className='ui red button' onClick={reset}>reset</button> <br/>

        <div className="ui icon input">
          <input type="text" id='searchbyid' placeholder="Search..."/>
          <i  id='ShowByID' onClick={searchById} className="circular search link icon"></i>
        </div>

        <div className="ui icon input">
          <input type="text" id="deleteById" placeholder="Delete..."/>
          <i  id='delete' onClick={DeleteOneNote} className="circular trash link icon"></i>
        </div>
        <button id='showAll' className='ui blue button'>my notes</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }


 class App extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
         <Fragment>    
           <FormApp/>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

in `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


let render = ()=>{
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
};

render(); // render the application

registerServiceWorker();

export {render};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do NOT ever throw in a "naked" Bootstrap column as you did there.

Here's what you need to make it work:

1. First create a Bootstrap container (div with a class `.container` or `.container-fluid`).
2. Then put a Bootstrap row inside (div with the `.row` class)
3. And then put your Bootstrap column(s) inside that row.

This is how you can make it work. Not impossible.

Bootstrap columns always need a `.row` as a parent and Bootstrap rows always need a `.container` or `.container-fluid` as a parent.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Also worth reading:

How the Bootstrap grid works behind the scenes:

http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Note: Even though that article is talking about Bootstrap 3, the described principles apply to the Bootstrap 4 grid as well.

Comment: crap. its been so long since i touched frontend. i forgot about row, container classes. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have few options.

1. Wrap your return() with some outter divs like

   `return(<div className="container"><div className="row>...)`
2. Add parent divs around your root element like
   `<div className="container"><div className="row"><div id="root">...`
3. Add inner divs to your `root` element, and then attach your react to whatever you need. `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('myInnerElement'));`